# Quick license manager webservice doesn't accept request

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I want to use the [Quick License Manager](http://soraco.co/quick-license-manager/) SOAP webservice to connect an e-commerce wordpress plugin to enable the user to buy a license and show it after a successful purchase.
So for now, I'm trying to call the function GetProductInfo to get the info of an existing product I created with the QLM Management Console.
I use the SoapClient php class but when I try to make a request I get this response :

> Error validating request: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. . Caller: GetProductInfo

I don't understand what's wrong with my request, so I need help...
Here is the code I use :

```
<?php 
$url = "https://quicklicensemanager.com/****/qlm/qlmservice.asmx";
$wsdl = $url . "?WSDL";
$soapClient = new SoapClient($wsdl, array(
    "encoding" => "utf8",
    "trace"    => TRUE,
    "version"  => SOAP_1_1
));
$req = sprintf(
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <QlmSoapHeader xmlns="http://www.interactive-studios.net/qlmweb">
      <CultureName>%s</CultureName>
      <UtcOffset>%d</UtcOffset>
    </QlmSoapHeader>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetProductInfo xmlns="http://www.interactive-studios.net/qlmweb">
      <eProductName>%s</eProductName>
      <productID>%d</productID>
      <major>%d</major>
      <minor>%d</minor>
    </GetProductInfo>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>', "en_US", 0, "The IO plug-in: Student License", 4, 1, 0);
echo '<pre>';
print_r(htmlentities($req));
echo '</pre>';

$action = "http://www.interactive-studios.net/qlmweb/GetProductInfo";

$res = $soapClient->__doRequest($req, $url, $action, 1);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($res);
echo '</pre>';
echo "=======================================================";
echo '<pre>';
print_r(htmlentities($soapClient->__getLastRequest()));
echo '</pre>';
echo "=======================================================";
echo '<pre>';
print_r($soapClient->__getLastRequestHeaders());
echo '</pre>';
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT**
Now I tried to change the field productID and it appears that it is the one that was wrong. So it needs to be a base64 string, so I updated my code :
    `</soap:Envelope>', "en_US", 0, "The IO plug-in: Student License", 4, 1, 0);` becomes `</soap:Envelope>', "en_US", 0, base64_encode("The IO plug-in: Student License"), 4, 1, 0);`

The new error message is :

> Error validating request: Length of the data to decrypt is invalid.. Caller: GetProductInfo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of searching, I found this in the [documentation](http://www.soracoinc.com/products/qlm/qlm.pdf), at page 121 :

> Note that all the methods exposed by the web service cannot be called with a URL except GetActivationKey
>   and ActivateKey. All other web methods implement a secure authentication mechanism that only accepts
>   requests from the QLM Console.

So, as I was trying to call *GetProductInfo*, it couldn't work outside the QLM Console.